# How to simulate click on (x, y) point of HTML document with Yahoo UI (JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, events, yui, simulation

DOCS http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#eventsimulation . but I do not understand how to do it( So how to simulate a mouse down at point ( X, Y) in the client area of some HTML Object with YUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
Y.Event.simulate(document.body, "click", { pageX:10,pageY:20 });
```

if i've understood well the documentation in this way you can simulate a click on the body at the coordinates X=10 and Y=20.
The first parameter is the html element, the second one is the event type and the last one the event data.